# Save multiple values from checkboxes in php

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I am very new to php and am teaching it to myself, so please keep that in mind.

I am working on a project that presents users with a list of items, from a database, with checkboxes, and allows the user to check them. I want to save the values of the checked fields. This is the line of code that prints all of the options. It prints a course code and course title, with a checkbox.

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name ='boxes'>" . $row['course'] . ' ' . $row['title'] . "<br>";
```

However, when I try to print the values selected, it doesn't work. I get an error that says `invalid argument supplied foreach()`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_courses'])){
  if(!empty($_POST['boxes'])){
    foreach($_POST['boxes'] as $selected ){
      echo $selected."</br>";
    }
  }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: You were pretty close, but you need to maker your name an array `name ='boxes[]'` if you want to find out what course was selected, you should consider including the ID of your DB rows as the value

Comment: I'm confused what you mean by the second part. You're correct that I want to know what course was selected, but I'm not sure what/where to change to show that. The DB row that I want to select is called 'course'.

Comment: When dealing with databases especially editing / updating you need a unique identifier so you know which row is which. Generally people just use an auto increment column named ID. If you already have that then you need to give the checkbox a value of that ID: `<input type='checkbox' value='{$row['ID'}' name ='boxes[]'>`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name ='boxes[]'>" . $row['course'] . ' ' . $row['title'] . "<br>";
```

**EDIT:**

To better answer the question:

You need to add the value="" attribute to your input fields. So if you have an ID in your $row array then it would be like this...

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name ='boxes[]' value=' . $row['id'] . '>" . $row['course'] . ' ' . $row['title'] . "<br>";
```

Now you should be able to get the selected id's from the populated values inside of the $_POST['boxes'] array. Just loop through them and do something with them like echo them out.

```
foreach ($_POST['boxes'] as $box_value) {
  echo $box_value . "<br>";
}
```

Only the boxes that are selected will be in the array and you will have the identifier for whatever courses were selected.

Comment: That kind of worked! Now it outputs that it's checked, but I want the output to be the value that was selected

Comment: @CaleighD _“but I want the output to be the value that was selected”_ - well then start by _adding_ a value to the checkbox, because currently you did not specify one (so that all checked checkboxes will only send the default `on`.)

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: @JoshuaEvan I got this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)" when I put the value in as what you had

Comment: @CaleighD Does your $row have an "ID" in the array? or any unique ID like "course_id" or something?

Comment: @JoshuaEvan I used the wrong quotation marks. I needed double quotes after " value ' " before the period and again, after the second period.